# Some resources aren't created from custom Helm chart

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to install Grafana using Helm chart. Because I need to deploy additional resources I have created a custom chart, which depends on following one:

```
  - name: grafana
    version: 8.4.3
    repository: oci://registry-1.docker.io/bitnamicharts
```

In order to import dashboards I have following values defined in `values.yaml`:

```
dashboardsProvider:
  enabled: true
dashboardsConfigMaps:
  - configMapName: k8s
    folderName: ''
    fileName: k8s.json
```

If I run `helm install my-release oci://registry-1.docker.io/bitnamicharts/grafana --values values.yaml --dry-run` I get all volumes in place:

```
      volumes:
        - name: data
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: g-grafana
        - name: dashboards-provider
          configMap:
            name: g-grafana-provider
        - name: k8s
          configMap:
            name: k8s
```

When I run however `helm install g. --dry-run` I see that several volumes aren't created:

```
      volumes:
        - name: data
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: g-grafana
```

What can be the reason? I checked the values are same in both cases:
Directly from repo (when it works fine):

```
dashboardsConfigMaps:
- configMapName: k8s
  fileName: k8s.json
  folderName: ""
dashboardsProvider:
  configMapName: ""
  enabled: true
```

From custom chart (when it doesn't work):

```
dashboardsConfigMaps:
- configMapName: k8s
  fileName: k8s.json
  folderName: ""
dashboardsProvider:
  configMapName: ""
  enabled: true
```

Update: I've realized when I copy templated from dependent chart to mine those volumes are added to the manifest. Does it mean templates aren't inherited but must be copied explicitly?